# Notepad++ tabs to spaces everywhere other than beginning of line

Tags: tabs, styles, notepad++, spaces

Due to a new coding style that I've been having to use I'm required to use tabs in the beginning of lines but spaces everywhere else to align things.

Is there a way to customize notepad++ to only replace tabs with spaces if it's not at the beginning of a new line?

Just as an example of what I mean I'll use this bit of 'code':

```
function someFunction():
    while(true):
        veryLongCodeStuff()  // Some comment
        shortCode()          // Aligned comment
```

Which I would have to write like this (where \t = tab and a "." represents a space):

```
function someFunction():
\twhile(true):
\t\tveryLongCodeStuff()..// Some comment
\t\tshortCode()..........// Aligned comment
```

Comment: I don't think it is possible in Npp. You should write a script in your favorite scripting language.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To convert existing files, I would suggest a two step approach:

1. replace **all** tabs with spaces (this can be done with Edit -> Blank operations -> TAB to Space )
2. replace spaces at the beginning of lines: do a regular expression find/replace like this:

   - Open Replace Dialog
   - **Find What:** `^([\t]?)( ){4}`  instead of 4 use the number of spaces you have configured as tab width
   - **Replace With:** `\1\t`
   - check **regular expression**
   - click **Replace All**: as each Replace All replaces only *one* indent level for *all* lines: repeat until the status bar of the find dialog tells you, that no more replacements were done (just keep Alt-A pressed for a second or two)

Comment: I've been doing something similar (instead I have a python script that I run before and after coding). But was hoping for something that deals with it for when I inevitably forget it half the time.

Thank you for your clear steps though.